# Can't access Mosets Tree on Joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I upgraded Joomla from 2.5 to 3.4 yesterday, after backing our website up. After the upgrading was done the whole website was down from about 10 minutes and then up and running again, but not completely.

We have 2 modules added that were not working (RSEvents Pro and Mosets Tree.) I was able to fix the issue with RSEvents Pro by changing the memory limit but no luck with Mostes tee. When I login to the backend of Joomla, go to Components, then Mosets Tree, I get 404 no component found error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade the Mosets component as well. Like RS Events you have to install the latest version compatible with Joomla 3, than only it will work.

Comment: I don't have the upgraded version of Mosets Tree and I don't have the login info to login and downloaded from the website ( I wasn't the admin who purchased it and no one in the org know anything about it)

Comment: You need the latest version that supports joomla 3. Probably you have an older version. So I recommend you to purchase the latest version or take help of a programmer to update Mosets tree.